# Android: bad quality background

Tags: android, background, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I want to ask why quality of background is low even when I have my options set ?
My code:

```
class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

 GameThread thread;

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
int screenW;
int screenH;
int bgrW;
int bgrH;
Bitmap bgr;

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context);

    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gamebg, options);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    }

@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    screenW = w;
    screenH = h;
    bgr = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgr, w, h, true);
    bgrW = bgr.getWidth();
    bgrH = bgr.getHeight();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Due to some answers found on this forum above code should act correct. I'am wondering if some declarations could be missing from onDraw() or onSizeChanged() area.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: where are you executing the above code?? in emulator or a device??

Comment: try out the below solution from GauravKumawat it worked for me ...

Comment: Here you are: [link](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/1776/device20130205095236.png), and original: [link](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5402/gamebg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the Nine-patch images instead of simple images :
go to the

```
android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\tools\draw9patch
```

and select the images you want and convert them into nine patch 
now they will look fine

Comment: Thank you but it seams that in my case draw9patch is not working and i got the same effect as before.

Comment: Moreover I got similar image in game menu. There I call it through my XML file, and it's quality is just fine as it is on a PC.

Comment: have you double clicked the draw9patch ??

Comment: em yes? I even opened the image and it saved the image as gamebg.9.png